# TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__ in odoo 11.0

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, jinja2, odoo-11, qweb

I am getting this error when loading my template on odoo 11.0: could it be the jinja2 syntax or what. Also tried to juggle with some brackets here and there but to no success. Any help will be appreciated.

```
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__ in odoo 11.0
```

this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <record id="template_dotmatrix_invoice" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Dot Matrix Invoice</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="account.model_account_invoice"/>
            <field name="subject">Dot Matrix Template for Invoice</field>
            <field name="body_html">![CDATA[
${'INVOICE'.rjust(30)} ${object.number}
${''.rjust(80,'-')}
${'Customer:'.rjust(20)} ${object.partner_id.display_name.ljust(20)} ${'Date:'.rjust(20)}
${object.date_invoice}
${' '.rjust(20)} ${object.partner_id.street.ljust(20)} ${'Salesperson:'.rjust(20)}
${object.user_id.name}
${' '.rjust(20)} ${object.partner_id.street2.ljust(20) if object.partner_id.street2 else ''.ljust(20)} ${'Sales Team:'.rjust(20)} ${object.team_id.name}
${' '.rjust(20)} ${object.partner_id.city.ljust(20)} ${'Currency:'.rjust(20)}
${object.currency_id.name}
${' '.rjust(20)} ${object.partner_id.country_id.name.ljust(20)}
${'Payment Term:'.rjust(20)} ${object.payment_term_id.name.ljust(20) if object.payment_term_id else ''.ljust(20)}

Invoice Lines
${''.rjust(80,'-')}
${'Product'.ljust(20)} ${'Qty'.rjust(6)} ${'UoM'.ljust(4)} ${'Price Unit'.rjust(13)} ${'Taxes'.ljust(10)} ${'Sub Total'.rjust(14)}
${''.rjust(80, '-')}
% for l in object.invoice_line_ids:
${l.product_id.name[:28].ljust(28)} ${"{:4,.0f}".format(l.quantity).rjust(6)} ${l.uom_id.name.ljust(4)} ${"{:4,.0f}".format(l.price_unit).rjust(13)} ${l.invoice_line_tax_ids.name.ljust(4) if l.invoice_line_tax_ids} ${"{:4,.0f}".format(l.price_subtotal).rjust(14)}
% endfor
${''.rjust(80, '-')}
${'Total Before Tax:'.rjust(59)} ${"{:20,.0f}".format(object.amount_untaxed).rjust(20)}
${'Tax:'.rjust(59)} ${"{:20,.0f}".format(object.amount_tax).rjust(20)}
${'Total:'.rjust(59)} ${"{:20,.0f}".format(object.amount_total).rjust(20)}
${'Balance:'.rjust(59)} ${"{:20,.0f}".format(object.amount_residual).rjust(20)}

]]
            </field>

        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. Apparently it was a reference error on the last line.

`object.residual` instead of `object.amount_residual`